# CSS Behavioral Extensions and HTML Component

Tags: css

Have CSS behavioral extensions HTML Component been adopted as a standard?

Answer (score 1):

no.

http://www.google.ae/search?q=css+behavioral+extensions

only a working draft exists.

Comment: Could better link to http://www.w3.org/TR/becss/, which will always point to the latest stable document